# Battlefield Premium: Gifting Back To Karkand to someone else

Tags: battlefield-3, origin, battlefield-premium

Having failed to find any means of contact someone relevant at EA....

I'm interested in getting Battlefield Premium, but I already have the base game which included the Back To Karkand DLC (limited edition).

Buying premium would just about pay for itself, if I wanted all the remaining DLCs as they are released, but it would be nice if I could make use of the Back to Karkand that I already have.

My (student) nephew has just got the vanilla game, and to save him a few pennies, it would be nice if I could 'gift' him B2K.

This kind of thing is possible under steam but is there anything equivalent under Origin?

Comment: I haven't noticed anything about getting an extra copy of B2K on my account, so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I also don't think it's possible, it wouldn't be on steam, either. Ask support at EA, that's what they're for.
Oh, but please tell us the answer, because then I'd also have a Back to Karkand to gift ;)

Comment: I finally found a means of emailing an appropriate dept in EA (took a while), and have sent in the question.... they claim to respond within 24hrs...fingers crossed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My response from EA (copied verbatim):

> no reduction is offer if you have already Back to Karkland DLC on the price of Premium is exactly the same price.

So... not the response I wanted, but at least they left me feeling warm and valued.